# Google Cloud App Engine subdomain not working

Tags: domain, google-app-engine, gcloud

Long story short- My subdomain is not working while domain is. Chrome just displays error- DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. Here are images of config.

[Google cloud config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elgyj.png)

[Domain dns config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8wJ0.png)

[Deploy.yaml config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejDSV.png)

I tried different things- Verified subdomain, added subdomain CNAME, added A and AAAA records for subdomain. Either it throws error, like now. Or it points to same location as domain.

Comment: Which subdomain? How long after creating the subdomain or modifying the subdomain have you waited? Your TTL is 14,400 seconds. You usually must wait that long after making a change.

Comment: server.tunnilehed.ee is subdomain. I wait 6h to 24h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain **server.tunnilehed.ee** returns NXDOMAIN. This error means that the DNS server does not have a resource record for that entry.

The solution is to create a resource record in your DNS server for **server.tunnilehed.ee** with a type of CNAME with a value of **ghs.googlehosted.com**.

Once you have corrected configured the resource record, you will need to wait for the **TTL** value specified in the SOA record before global DNS servers that have already cached the NXDOMAIN response to refresh their cache. This is typically either one hour or 24 hours. You can use an Internet service such as https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx to test your DNS server settings.

Comment: Then you have more than one problem. Implement my answer as this is required as the first step in the solution. The custom domain settings appear correct. That means the next problem is with your **deploy.yaml** file. change the entry for url:"\*//server.tunnlehed.ee/*"  to url: "server.tunnilhed.ee/*"